# How to set height and width of :before by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, web

I got a CSS3 tag called `body:before`,
and I want to use JavaScript to set the height and width of `body:before`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you selecting *before* the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. One possiblity is to use a class or ID:

```
.someClass:before {
    /*Styles here*/
}
```

You can then apply the `someClass` class to the elements in question by setting the `className` property:

```
yourElement.className = "someClass";
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it in another way